# Automatic rounding in dplyr::summarise() function

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

I am wondering if there is any easy way to specify the number of digits reported by `summarise` in `dplyr`, ideally using a native `dplyr` or other `tidyverse` function?

Here's some toy data

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10, length.out = 40),
                 large = rnorm(40, 100, 15),
                 small = rnorm(40, 0.5, 0.02))
```

If we then summarise via

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mL = mean(large), mS = mean(small))
```

We get

```
#   group    mL    mS
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a     104.  0.496
# 2 b      97.6 0.506
```

Note that without specifying any rounding the variable with the higher mean has been rounded to 1 decimal place and the variable with the smaller mean has been rounded to 3.

Now want if we want the variable with the larger mean to also be reported to 3 decimal places? If we include a command to round like so

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mL = round(mean(large),3), mS = mean(small))
```

There is no change in the output

```
#   group    mL    mS
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a     104.  0.496
# 2 b      97.6 0.506
```

Only if we use the `format()` function can we obtain what we are after

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mL = format(round(mean(large),3),3), mS = mean(small))

  group      mL    mS
  <fct> <chr>   <dbl>
1 a     103.888 0.496
2 b     97.626  0.506
```

**Is there an easier way to do this?** Ideally using some kind of tidyverse function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is to do with the way tibbles are printed. The actual numbers in the data frame still have all the decimal places they are just not displayed when printing the tibble.

You can use `as.data.frame` or `print.data.frame()` which will show you more decimal points (depending on your `getOption("digits")`). You can also change the tibble settings but my understanding is that these are always based on significant figures rather than decimal points (so your values >100 will have fewer decimal points than values <100) See 
https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html for tibble printing options

So

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mL = round(mean(large),3), mS = round(mean(small),3)) %>%
     as.data.frame()
```

will give you values to 3 decimal places, and

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mL = mean(large), mS = mean(small))  %>%
     as.data.frame()
```

will show to `getOption("digits")` decimal places (I think 7 is default).

Also note if you do want to do the same thing to multiple columns in summarise, `summarise_at()` can be very helpful, e.g.

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_at(c("large","small"), ~round(mean(.),3)) %>% 
    print.data.frame()
```